# How hibernate caching works

Tags: hibernate, caching

I need some guidance on how hibernate caches the query results. For example if I issue two fetch operation one after another with exact same parameter, will hibernate connect to DB two times, run query against db two times and fetch the results or it will cache the results from the first time?

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    App app = new App();


    try{
        factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().
                addPackage("com.mantech.test").
                addAnnotatedClass(Address.class).
                buildSessionFactory();

        //addAddress();
        app.listAddress();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        app.listAddress();

     }catch (Throwable ex) { 
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
     }
}

   private void listAddress( ){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try{
           tx = session.beginTransaction();
           List employees = session.createQuery("FROM Address a where a.city='Test'").setCacheable(true).list(); 
           System.out.println("Fetching Done");

           for (Iterator iterator = 
                             employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
               Address address = (Address) iterator.next(); 
              System.out.print("City Name: " + address.getCity()); 
              System.out.print("  Country Name: " + address.getCountry()); 
              System.out.println("  ID: " +address.getId()); 
           }
           tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
           if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
           e.printStackTrace(); 
        }finally {
           session.close(); 
        }
     }
```

When I tried above code it prints select query two time which gives me impression that it connects to db and runs query two time (I am printing query in log files). I have used query cache. My expectation is it should run the query against the DB only once since and cache the results.

Comment: You have told Hibernate it could cache the query, but you haven't told it to use a second-level cache, and you haven't told it which cache implementation it must use: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache

Comment: So If I don't configure second level cache it won't cache the results. I think first level cache should still work here.

Comment: The first level cache never cache queries. And even if it did, it's associated to the Session, and you're using two different sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used query cache. For query cache you also need to enable the 2nd level cache:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactoryy</property>
```

Comment: @njain have a look [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works.html)